# how to change specific path images using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i would like to know can we rewrite/change **specific** path images using htaccess ?

From :

```
http://116.0.121.242/images/default_img.jpg
```

To :

```
http://116.0.121.242/~citecom/images/default_img.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://116.0.121.242/~citecom/images/$1 [L,R=301]
```